# How to load a view when its outlets and actions are contained in the view being loaded?

Tags: ios, uiview, nib

I like to create a small custom view class named `Configurator` that derives from `UIView`. I would like the `IBOutlets` and `IBActions` to be placed in the `Configurator` itself (and not in any view controller). I have created the layout in IB where I also indicated that the *Files Owner* belong to class `Configurator`.

My problem is that when I load the view, using the code snippet below, I have to supply the owner. But the owner is the object beeing loaded.`

> NSArray *arr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"configurator"
>   owner:**????** options:nil]; Configurator *viewConf = [arr
>   objectAtIndex:0];

Question: *How to load a view when its outlets and actions are contained in the view being loaded?*

EDIT: My main-view will load the small Configurator-view and display it in a small part of the screen. I cannot set owner to *self* because that would imply that the outlets and actions where  located in the main view.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a controller loads a view. A view loading itself does not seem right. When you have a separate controller loading the view, the owner will be the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the owner as `self`. This will work same as we use Custom `UITableViewCell` as shown below:

```
NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
cell = (MyCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
```

This will refer to your custom view *IBOutlets* and *IBActions* only.

Hope this will clear your doubts.